# Regex - Recuperando propriedade de arquivo pré formatado

Tags: regex

A ideia é desenvolver uma ferramenta que selecione campos de um arquivo pré formatado segundo um schema especifico:
Schema:

```
1.   
[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris efficitur 
laoreet gravida. Nunc lacinia elit in nulla ultrices viverra eget eget 
massa. Phasellus suscipit pharetra ex non euismod. 
Sed mollis laoreet odio id blandit. Maecenas vel orci sed lacus commodo 
commodo et a mauris.


{asd123ASD/asd123ASD/a1A/a1A/a1A -:_ }

]
```

Basicamente um arquivo de texto com um índice e um conteúdo entre os `[ ]` que se destacam uma string não delimitada e um bloco de comando delimitados por `{ }`.

O objetivo é capturar os dados em grupos. Ex.: Índices, Textos Comandos.

Vi que uma forma "fácil" de se resolver é usando `RegEx`.

Então cheguei a isto:

```
(\d{1}[[:punct:]]\s*\[){1}(.*\s*\{)(.*\s*\])
```

https://regex101.com/r/Md4L6b/1

Mas esta retornando apenas 2 match onde deveriam ter 5.

Alguém pode me dizer onde estou errando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que alguns índices são diferentes do primeiro e do quarto. Os Índices 2,3 e 5 possuem espaços entre os texto, o que o regex não consegue dar match

Abaixo o regex que consegue pegar

```
(\d[[:punct:]])\s*\[([a-zA-Z\s[[:punct:]]*)\s*{(.*)}\s*\]
```

Veja funcionando https://regex101.com/r/Md4L6b/2